# Mojo::Home where is the spew method?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

Is the method silently gone?
This produce an error, I have no clue why.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Mojo::Home;
my $f = Mojo::Home->new->path('test.txt');
$f->spew('test');
```

`Can't locate object method "spew" via package "Mojo::File" at ...`

It should be working:
https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojo/File#spew

Comment: What version of Mojo::File do you have?

Comment: Mojo::File doesn't contain a version. You'll have to check Mojolicious's version.

Comment: you can use `spurt()` method. ```$f->spurt('test');```

Comment: Mojo was 9.33 (I now upgrade to 9.35) 
strange. I did read the source code and doc:
# DEPRECATED!
sub spurt {
  deprecated 'Mojo::File::spurt is deprecated in favor of Mojo::File::spew';
  shift->spew(join '', @_);
}

Comment: In general, Mojolicious expects you to pay attention to its rapid release process. The developers signal changes a couple months in advance and expect you to stay up-to-date. When you run into these sorts of problems, reading the [Changes](https://metacpan.org/dist/Mojolicious/changes) file is often my first stop.

Comment: That's not the problem, but if they rename a function they should somewhere notice it in the documentation. I did use the function the first time and my Mojolicious was not so old, that this was my first thought.
and a couple of month in context of an over 30 year old language sound to me strange.

Answer (score 2):

`->spew` was added in 9.34 as an alias for `->spurt`, at which time the name `->spurt` became deprecated.

So, either

- Upgrade to 9.34 or newer.
- Use `->spurt` instead of `->spew`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the answer is the Version. I used yesterday 9.33 and there were no such method. If you upgrade to 9.35 it is.

It's not nice with this small upgrade to add a new function without any comment in the Docs. additionaly with the old function you may get now a warning.